# Why isn't scanf( ) waiting for input from keyboard?

Tags: c, printf, structure, scanf, fflush

I have below C code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //Declaring structure book.
    struct book
    {
            char name;
            float price;
            int pages;
    };

    struct book b[5];

    int i;
    //Below loop takes the info if 5 books from user
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
            printf("Enter name, price, and pages: ");
            fflush( stdin );
            scanf("%c%f%d",&b[i].name,&b[i].price,&b[i].pages);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

However when I compile and run, something strange happens.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Enter name, price, and pages: A 23 34
Enter name, price, and pages: B 34 54
Enter name, price, and pages: Enter name, price, and pages: C 56 78
Enter name, price, and pages: -bash-4.1$
```

You can see that when i = 2, scanf() does NOT wait for keyboard. Then when i = 3, scanf() waits for keyboard input. Again in i=4, scanf() does NOT wait for keyboard input.

I guess I have used

```
fflush(stdin);
```

in the correct place. I don't want the return key to be in the buffer in the next scanf().

To debug, i tried not to use fflush(stdin) and see what heppens. But even without the fflush(stdin), same thing happens when i run the program. So I guess fflush(stdin) is not causing this problem.

Please anyone point out, where my program is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Don't use `fflush( stdin );` it's for stdout 2. `scanf(" %c %f %d",&b[i].name,&b[i].price,&b[i].pages);` Space and fixed

Comment: @Rizier123: You mean `" %c %f %d"`? Since there are spaces between the numbers.

Comment: @TimČas the spaces between the numbers are irrelevant for the format specifier, the one left at the end is important.

Comment: `printf` statements would come in handy here. Basic debugging.

Comment: @user3121023: Ah, right. Still a good idea for code style reasons, though.

Comment: @TimČas, it works ok if i use scanf(" %c %f %d") , regardless of if i use fflush(stdin) or not. but why is this space needed ?

Comment: @user266168: You should *not* use `fflush(stdin);`. You probably meant `fflush(stdout);` so that your prompt is displayed. And the space is needed because it makes `scanf` ignore leading spaces.

Comment: the space at the beginning of a scanf format string is important.  While some of the input/conversion specifiers will skip over white space, %c is not one of them.  The leading space will enable scanf to skip over leading white space, like the leftover newline from the prior entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C11 standard explains how `%c` works:

> §7.21.6.2/8 Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function)
>   are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n`
>   specifier.

As such, the linefeed produced by the enter key is consumed by %c. You can fix this by adding a space before `%c`:

> §7.21.6.2/5 A directive composed of white-space character(s) is
>   executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character
>   (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The
>   directive never fails.

Your code becomes `scanf(" %c%f%d",&b[i].name,&b[i].price,&b[i].pages);`.

---

Note that `fflush` should **not** be used here.

> §7.21.5.2/2 If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which
>   the most recent operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes
>   any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host
>   environment to be written to the file; otherwise, **the behavior is
>   undefined.**

Comment: i got the expected results when I put a ' ' before %c. However I am still not able to understand why fflush(stdin) didn't solve this issue. I guess i should read somewhere what exaclt fflush() does.

Comment: @user266168 the answer is **undefined**. It could do anything. Don't rely on it.