# How to make fgets() ignore a \n at beginning?

Tags: c, string, scanf, fgets

I have below C code.

```
struct student
{
    int rollNumber;
    char name[20];
    char department[20];
    char course[20];
    int yearOfJoining;
};

int main()
{
    // Creating a 'student' variable.
    struct student s;

    // Take the info of student from keyboard

            printf("Student \n-------------------\n");
            printf("Roll no: ");
            scanf("%d",&s.rollNumber);
            printf("Name: ");
            fgets(s.name, 20, stdin);
            //scanf("%s",&s.name);
            printf("Department: ");
            fgets(s.department, 20, stdin);
            //scanf("%s",&s.department);
            printf("Course: ");
            fgets(s.course, 20, stdin);
            //scanf("%s",&s.course);
            printf("Year of joining: ");
            scanf("%d",&s.yearOfJoining);

   return 0;
}
```

However when I compile and run this code below happens.

```
-bash-4.1$ ./a.out
Student
-------------------
Roll no: 1
Name: Department: ECE
Course: CE
Year of joining: 2006
-bash-4.1$
```

You can see that first `fgets()` doesn't not wait for the string input from keyboard.

I am sure this is because `fgets()` is taking the `\n` which was in the input buffer after I gave the roll number and pressed `ENTER`.

When I try with `scanf`(which is commented out in the code above) instead of `fgets`, it works fine. However I want to use `fgets()`, not `scanf()`.

Something like this happened to me while getting a character from keyboard (`%c`) yesterday, in which case i could give a `%c` (with a space before `%c`) to make `scanf()` ignore the `\n`. This problem was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467195).

However, I can't do something like that with `fgets()` as i don't specify (%s). (Also, surprisingly I didn't have to give a space before %s for `scanf()`, which i initially thought I needed to).

Comment: Simple: Call it, and repeat if the buffer contains the string `"\n"` afterwards.

Comment: @Deduplicator I appreciate your response. However, could you please elaborate it. I am actually not able to understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: You got a bug in line printf("student %d\n--------\n"); . The %d is in error or you have missed a parameter.

Comment: @rhubarbdog Yea that was a typing mistake when i typed my question here. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the original idea does not seem to work, so another try:

```
scanf("%d",&s.rollNumber);
printf("Name: ");
fgets(s.name, 20, stdin); /* capture the new line */
fgets(s.name, 20, stdin);
```

Original idea:
Simply tell `scanf` to also capture the newline:

```
scanf("%d\n",&s[i].rollNumber);
```

Comment: I want to to use fgets(), and not scanf().

Comment: I don't understand why you want to avoid `scanf`, e.g. `scanf("%19s\n", &s.name)` would read in the name and would also be safe.

Comment: @mat69 Sorry, initially I thought you were telling to use scanf() to get the string. Now i realised that you initially asked to use scanf() to get in Roll number including \n, so that fgets() would not be impacted. However if I use scanf("%d\n",&s.rollNumber), the program gets stuck , and wont ask for name untill i press something in keyboard and hit ENTER, after which again same thing happens.

Comment: @user266168 printf might buffer the output, so your "Name:" prompt might not show. do `fflush(stdout);` after all your printf() statements that doesn't print a newline at the end.

Comment: @nos I used "%d\n", but this isn't solving the problem. After i type a number and hit ENTER, the program gets stuck until i type something and hit enter again. After which same problem is there again.

Comment: @mat69 Using fgets() twice first to capture the \n, and next to capture the string worked. Thanks for the suggestion. However is there any way we can code saying if there is \n in input buffer, then use fgets twice , if not use fgets once ? I mean can i access the buffer and see its content? ? And use a if-else so that if there is anything(\n) in buffer then use fgets() twice, else once ?

Comment: You could use `getc` in combination with `ungetc`.

Comment: @user266168 I'm telling you that you need to insert a line with fflush(stdout); right after the `printf("Name: ");` if you use scanf("%d\n" ...